# Update Query Doesn't Work But No Error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

(I code VB.NET and use ms access 2016 as database)

I execute this query but nothing happen. I wonder whats wrong. no error when i run it. i debugged it and all the values in the variables are also correct.

no changes happened in my db too

```
 If Not (TextBoxID.Text = "" Or TextBoxNama.Text = "") Then
        Try
            Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE tblEmployees SET Nama = @nama  WHERE IDEmployee = @ide"  
            Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand

            With sqlcommand
                .CommandText = sqlquery
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ide", TextBoxID.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", TextBoxNama.Text)

                .Connection = FormMain.conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            ButtonEdit.Text = "EDIT"
            ButtonEdit.Image = My.Resources.edit
            GroupBox1.Enabled = False
            ButtonNew.Enabled = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    Else
        MsgBox("Data cannot be empty!")
    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MS Access doesn't have **named** parameters - but rather **positional** parameters.

So you **must specify** the parameters in the **correct order** in which they appear in your SQL statement. And you're *not* doing to right now.

Change your code to this:

```
If Not (TextBoxID.Text = "" Or TextBoxNama.Text = "") Then
    Try
        Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE tblEmployees SET Nama = @nama WHERE IDEmployee = @ide"  
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand

        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = sqlquery
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", TextBoxNama.Text) 
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ide", TextBoxID.Text)

            .Connection = FormMain.conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You **must set the value** for `@nama` **first**, before you set the value for `@ide`, since that's the order in which these parameters appear in your MS Access SQL statement.